# Prevent draggable uiimage being moved beyond point on y axis

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a uiimage that has a pan gesture enabling the user to move the image along the y axis. How can I make it impossible for the image position from becoming <100 for example.

Basically, I have a draggable image that I don't want to be dragged beyond a certain point on the y axis.

I had a long search for something like this but found nothing that I thought was relevent enough to me.

I am very new to programming and would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code of the method that handles the panning gesture?

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide any code, but now that I've fixed it there's not much point anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pan handling method you can use something like this:

```
 - (void)panHandle:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture 
 {
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.view];//get the coordinate
    //check for current position of image and update only 
    //if it is below 100 or a desired value 
    if(point.y <= 100)
    {
      //update the coordinate of image
    }
    else
    {
      point.y = 100;
      //update the coordinate. This will make your view move on x axis keeping y limits
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can drag the image, you have surely a gesture recognizer that calls a callback method during dragging repeatedly.  And you probably use the current coordinate provided by the gesture recognizer to update the center property of the image that you drag.
So you could check the current coordinate in the callback method, and if it crossed a certain border, you simply do no longer update the center property of the image.
Or did I understand something wrong?
Maybe you could provide some code. This would make an answer easier.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer helped me think up a solution but the answer given by someone else got the same solution as me so I've marked that one as the answer. I upvoted your answer though since it helped me out.